# How to keep two read only collection synced with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a mongoose model called `Products` which I feed from an external system (a google spreadsheet).

Every time the spreadsheet changes, I get an event and I need to find out what changed and update `Products` collection accordingly.

The easiest method I though about was:

1. On spreadsheet changed event, delete all documents in `Product` collection
2. Insert the entire new collection of products I got from the spreadsheet into `Products` collection again.

This is hardly efficient, but it's an easy and clean solution, assuming the collection is not very big and doesn't update too frequently.

Any other method I can think of involves iterating both the updated google spreadsheet and the `Products` collection and comparing them to each other.

Is there an inherited way of doing this ? perhaps a more efficient algo ?

Comment: Why not update the documents using `$set` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to insert into a new empty collection with a temporary name and then rename it to overwrite the existing collection atomically.

You could also consider doing an `upsert` on each document that has been created or updated in the spreadsheet and then delete any deleted documents.